# 'const' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6')

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am using `eslint-config-airbnb-base` npm package for `eslint`...I just created `.eslintrc.json` file and also setup eslint package in my **IDE** ..the problem is that I am getting warning for `const` about **ES6** can any one please provide me the details that how I can config **ES6** for `const`
I am getting this warning "**const' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz). (W104)jshint(W104)**"...
please Provide me details that how to config for this warning..thank you

`.eslintrc.json file`

```
{
    "extends": "airbnb-base"
}
```

Comment: airbnb-base already enables ES6. Make sure you have the latest version and make sure eslintrc you listed is in effect.

Comment: The latest airbnb-base version is 13.

Comment: 13.1.0 version for the same but ...issue is still persist

Comment: Then the second part, *make sure eslintrc you listed is in effect*. It should be either one or another. Otherwise you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: right now in eslintrc file only extends airbnb-config..any thing else I have to add..?

Comment: No, you don't have to. I expect airbnb-base  to work out of the box, and the answer already correctly explains how ES6 could be enabled alone, it should work as well. That neither of them don't work suggests that something is wrong on your side. It's impossible to say what exactly it is. There could be another eslintrc file elsewhere that overrides the file you listed. You can start with making syntax mistake in the file and checking if ESLint will complain. You didn't mention anything about IDE, it could be a problem that is specific to it and not ESLint in general.

Comment: Sir I am using visual studio code version:1.31.0-1549443364 and I installed eslint package in this IDE I checked twice all that things which effects and it's perfect ...Now you are right that it conflicts with my npm package and IDE package

Comment: Desabled ESlint pacakage of IDE and enabled it again then it worked fine..thank you so much for your help

Comment: Glad you sorted this out.

Answer (score 4):

[eslint: Specifying Parser Options](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options)

you should add `parserOptions` to your `.eslintrc.json` file

```
{
 "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Zaan Chi's answer,

If you want to use ES6 only for a particular file, or dont want to change the eslint json, You can add this comment to the top of the file.

```
/* jshint esversion: 6 */
```

*Note that if you are using ES6 for your entire project, it is better to add it to the JSON.*